# How to implode (reverse of explode) only non-null values in pandas. Merge multiple rows into single row using pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I am working on Python Pandas.

I have a pandas dataframe with columns like this:

| ID | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York |
| 1 | '' |
| 1 | Atlanta |
| 2 | Tokyo |
| 2 | Kyoto |
| 2 | '' |
| 3 | Paris |
| 3 | Bordeaux |
| 3 | '' |
| 4 | Mumbai |
| 4 | '' |
| 4 | Bangalore |
| 5 | London |
| 5 | '' |
| 5 | Bermingham |

Note the empty cells in the column are either empty string ('') or Nan or None. (For simplicity lets just say they are empty strings ('')).

And I want the result to be like this:

| ID | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York, Atlanta |
| 2 | Tokyo, Kyoto |
| 3 | Paris, Bordeaux |
| 4 | Mumbai, Bangalore |
| 5 | London, Bermingham |

In short, I want to group by ID and then getting the list (by removing the empty strings).

I have a sample code for this but it actually gives me result with empty strings, I want to remove empty strings.

```
dataFrame.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False)
                  .agg({'Cities': lambda x: x.tolist()})
```

It gives me result like this:

| ID | Cities |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New York, ,Atlanta |
| 2 | Tokyo, Kyoto, |
| 3 | Paris, Bordeaux, |
| 4 | Mumbai, , Bangalore |
| 5 | London, , Bermingham |

But I dont want empty strings...

Please help me here.

Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: What should expected output look like? Please, add it into your question.

Comment: Just added. Sorry for that. I was still editing my post.

Comment: Try: `df[df.Cities.ne("")].groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg(list)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try replacing empty string by `NaN` and then add [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to the aggregate lambda function, as follows:

```
df['Cities'] = df['Cities'].replace('', np.nan)

(df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
                  .agg({'Cities': lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()})
)
```

**Result:**

```
   ID                Cities
0   1   [New York, Atlanta]
1   2        [Tokyo, Kyoto]
2   3     [Paris, Bordeaux]
3   4   [Mumbai, Bangalore]
4   5  [London, Bermingham]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also perform the operations at the Series level, by [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) out the unneeded values like empty string (`''`), [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to remove the missing/empty values, then [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) into whatever type needed, like a `list`:

```
new_df = (
    df['Cities']
        .mask(df['Cities'].eq(""))  # Replace Empty String with NaN
        .dropna()  # Exclude NaN
        .groupby(df['ID'])  # Groupby ID
        .aggregate(list)  # Join Into List
        .reset_index()  # Convert Back to DataFrame
)
```

Or filter out unneeded rows by condition:

```
new_df = (
    # Filter out by condition
    df.loc[df['Cities'].ne("") & df['Cities'].notnull(), 'Cities']
        .groupby(df['ID'])  # Groupby ID
        .aggregate(list)  # Join Into List
        .reset_index()  # Convert Back to DataFrame
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   ID                Cities
0   1   [New York, Atlanta]
1   2        [Tokyo, Kyoto]
2   3     [Paris, Bordeaux]
3   4   [Mumbai, Bangalore]
4   5  [London, Bermingham]
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
    'Cities': ['New York', "", 'Atlanta', 'Tokyo', 'Kyoto', "", 'Paris',
               'Bordeaux', "", 'Mumbai', "", 'Bangalore', 'London', "",
               'Bermingham']
})
```